# How to execute update operation when MyBatis's passed parameter data type is java map?

Tags: mybatis

I am a beginner of mybatis,recently i want to use mybatis to execute a update operation.The parameter date type of mybatis is java map,the map include all i want to update field in database,Like username,age,password,,,but the map's key not just the field name of the database and i want to use mybatis's foreach what should i do?

Here is mybatis sql mapper

```xml
<update id="updateData" parameterType="map">
    UPDATE myDataBase SET
<foreach item="value" index="key " collection="param" separator=",">
    <if test="key != oldPageNo and key != oldNo">
         ${key}=#{value}
    </if>
</foreach>
    WHERE 
    ID = #{param[oldNo]} AND PAGE = #{param[oldPageNo]}
</update>
```

Here is the interface

```java
 int updateData(@Param("param")Map<String, Object> param);
```

The error:
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'oldPageNo' not found. Available parameters are [param, param1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your parameter named param is a `Map<String, Object>`. to get a key's value, you have to pass a `String` into its `get(Object key)` method.

so you have to change the following from

```
ID = #{param[oldNo]} AND PAGE = #{param[oldPageNo]}
```

to

```
ID = #{param['oldNo']} AND PAGE = #{param['oldPageNo']}
```

you should also change your comparison in if-tag from

```
<if test="key != oldPageNo and key != oldNo">
```

to

```
<if test="key != 'oldPageNo' and key != 'oldNo'">
```